# Making an image with the 'hip' Haskell library pixelwise

Tags: haskell, image-processing, pixel

I'm trying to make an image with the **hip** library for Haskell. The following code works fine when I run it in ghci:

```hs
let grad_color = makeImageR VU (200, 200) (\(i, j) -> PixelRGB (fromIntegral i) (fromIntegral j) (fromIntegral (i + j))) / 400

writeImage "images/grad_color.png" grad_color
```

Now I would like to isolate the function which constructs the image. I tried (my attempt is somewhat random cause I'm lost)::

```hs
fun :: (Int, Int) -> Pixel RGB Word8
fun (i, j) = PixelRGB (fromIntegral i) / 200 * (fromIntegral j) / 200 (fromIntegral (i + j))) / 400
```

But this function does not compile. The final goal is to put pieces together:

```hs
gradColor :: (Int, Int) -> ????
gradColor (m, n) = makeImageR VU (m, n) fun
```

I know there's a lot of errors, but again I'm lost with the signatures.

Comment: So you just want to divide it by 200/400?

Comment: You need a lotta more parentheses. As you've written it you try to divide the function `(PixelRGB (fromIntegral i))` by `200` which doesn't make a lot of sense. Remember functions bind tighter than operators.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to produce an example. And this was for more complicated than divided 200/400 ^^ Sorry for the parentheses in my question.

```hs
module TestHip
    (colorFun
    , myImage
    , gradientColor
    , saveImage
    ) where
import Graphics.Image
    ( makeImageR, writeImage, RGB, Image, Pixel(PixelRGB), VU(..) )


colorFun :: (Int, Int) -> Pixel RGB Double
colorFun (i, j) =
  PixelRGB (fromIntegral i) (fromIntegral j) (fromIntegral (i + j)) / 400

myImage :: ((Int, Int) -> Pixel RGB Double) -> (Int, Int) -> Image VU RGB Double
myImage thefun (m, n) = makeImageR VU (m, n) thefun

gradientColor :: Image VU RGB Double
gradientColor = myImage colorFun (400, 400)

saveImage :: IO ()
saveImage = writeImage "images/mygradient.png" gradientColor
```

Run `saveImage´ and you'll get this image:

[image]

## Edit: a pretty one

[image]